# Wouldn't a Star Trek mirror universe become unrecognisable within a few generations?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-tos, mirror-universe

In the *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* episode "Crossover" two members of the DS9 crew cross over to an alternate universe. It is the same universe that Kirk went to many years earlier in the TOS episode "Mirror, Mirror."

In the episode "Crossover" Quark is killed. So now there's no Quark in the mirror universe. Odo was also killed so now there's no Odo in the mirror universe.

I'm just using these as examples to show how quickly (within a day) changes occur between the mirror universes.

In addition circumstances would change. For example Sisko would not meet his wife on the beach and as a result Jake would never be born. O'Brien never meets his wife, never gets married, and has no children. Or maybe they meet different women to have children with. Or they could even meet the same women but have different offspring with them because they procreated at different times (different egg and sperm).

Other unions would form creating different offspring due to these different sets of circumstances. Some people might get killed or remain alive due to different circumstances in one universe or the other. All of this would result in creating different offspring.

Assuming that they're closely 'mirrored' during Kirk's time, how is it possible that 4 to 5 generations later many of the characters are still the same, in the same places, are associating with the same people, etc.?

Is there some sort of connection or mechanism between the two mirrors that moves them back into sync somehow with each other?

(Although outside of the actual personnel everything else seems to always be radically different between the universes with the exception of Spock whom we always know is the same in any universe.)

Comment: The implication is that there's a certain amount of historical inertia at play, keeping the timelines somewhat consistent.

Comment: @Richard what is "historical inertia?"

Comment: “Sisko would never meet his wife on the beach and as a result Jake would never be born” — [Mirror Sisko actually did marry Mirror Jennifer](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Through_the_Looking_Glass_(episode)), although [they never had a son](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Crossover_%28episode%29#Trivia).

Comment: @JMFB - Where large events seems to *want* to occur, as if guided by an external force

Comment: Large events? It seems like large events are completely different(alliances, power, control, etc.). However small events like an identical individual appearing in both universes in the same general area are mirrored. Unless you're saying the cumulative affect of a bunch of individuals is a large event. But then why wouldn't something like the formation of Starfleet, an alliance by the Klingons, Cardassians, and Bajorans, etc. not be mirrored. And how does STU deal with the offspring issue? Is the time individuals procreate considered historical inertia? The offspring thing is confusing to me.

Comment: I'm not sure it's established there is only ONE mirror universe. Perhaps it's simply the closest of current alternate realities, which implies it's most similar.

Comment: This question is vaguely familiar; I don't think it was asked before, but brought up as a side point to another question.  Would be good to track it down and link them, assuming I'm not imagining it

Comment: @Izkata When I asked the question I looked around but couldn't find anything, at least from what I saw, that addressed this issue. I've always been confused by the alternate universe, mirror universe, alternate timeline, etc. episodes. Remember the one with Kirk and Lazarus? Same kind of thing. Actually this is a good question.

Comment: If by chance you've read both *A Fire Upon the Deep* and *Permutation City*, and are interested in these questions of how mirror universes can be the way they are, I cannot recommend Eliezer Yudkowski's ["The Finale of the Ultimate Meta Mega Crossover"](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5389450/1/The_Finale_of_the_Ultimate_Meta_Mega_Crossover) strongly enough.

Comment: @JMFB "What is the difference" between those types of universes/timelines I believe has been asked before, that might be what I'm thinking of

Comment: @Izkata when I wrote this is a good question I meant a new question about alternate realities, etc. I started drafting one and was searching for all sorts of examples, and got confused with what I wanted to actually ask, lol. I went to sleep to reconsider the question. So maybe it's not such a good question or maybe I just have to rethink it.

Comment: Timey Whimey Wibbly Wobbly fixed points in time. Also star trek has temporal shielding and other technology and temporal particles at play, so temporal inertia makes sense.

Comment: @cde But doesn't that temporal shielding get pierced with a multiflux gamma tetryon ultrium antiproton pulse particle beam coming from a tertiary subspace flux-capacitor nacelle manifold?

Comment: Only if you forget to reverse the polarity of the deflector.

Comment: I can only assume the fact that it is a "mirror" universe, as opposed to a parallel universe or something like that, implies some kind of reflection between universes that tends to keep the main characters in sync.

Comment: bravo @Beta for *A Fire Upon the Deep* and *Permutation City* combo!

Comment: If we apply the multiverse theory (all possible universes exist), then it's just a matter of the "mirror" universe being the one that gets bridged to by the transporter, etc., which just happens to be the one which evolves in just the way necessary to bring it to the state it is seen.

Answer (score 9):

(I'd prefer to make this a comment, but it's too long.)

I haven't seen "Crossover" and don't remember "Mirror, Mirror" very well, but there is a way to make this work-- at least well enough for a soft science fiction setting like "Star Trek".

Suppose there are many universes, and a mechanism that allows people to jump from one to another on rare occasions. And suppose that this mechanism tends to choose two universes that are *nearby*, where the cosmic definition of *nearby* is that some things in the physical vicinity (e.g. people, ships) are physically almost identical, but large and distant things (e.g. societies, races) can be wildly different. The bias also doesn't seem to apply to very small-scale things like brain patterns, so that although a "double" has the same face as person we know, he may not have the same personality. He might have a different name, too, but the Universal Translator can smooth that over. This is enough to explain either episode<sup>*</sup>.

To explain *both* episodes -- and the stated fact that both groups of people visited the same other universe -- requires something more. Just to recapitulate, "they went to the same place" means that when the DS9 officers found themselves in a strange version of DS9 (the station, not the series), they could consult the history books and read about something that happened a century earlier on board the *Enterprise*: some of the senior crew had acted goofy for several hours, showing mercy to enemies, unfamiliarity with shipboard disciplinary procedures, and surprise at the state of Spock's facial hair. Then they started acting normal again and reported having been on a version of the *Enterprise* weirdly bereft of torture and treachery, with a clean-shaven Spock and very few daggers. This corresponds exactly with the DS9 officers' memories of their own history, in which several members of the senior crew of the *Enterprise* had turned into disoriented, vicious, scheming psychopaths for a few hours, then recovered and told of-- you get the idea.

According to the *"Nearby"* rule, the DS9 jumpers should have found themselves in a self-consistent universe, in a station similar to their own, full of people who look like the ones they left behind, but with distant things different from what they remembered. It makes no sense that in such a universe, a *distant* group of people, a century earlier, should resemble a corresponding group from the travelers' home universe's history. It's not required by the *"Nearby"* rule, it can't apply to all groups of distant people (otherwise even one "didn't have a child" divergence would break the whole thing), and if it's not required then it's wildly improbable.

So let's add one more feature to the mechanism: laziness. It chooses two universes, A and B, that are similar to each other in a couple of different spots-- and those spots are where people can jump. It is pure coincidence that a universe that produced a twin of "our" *Enterprise* also produced a twin of "our" DS9, with no causal connection between them and everything in other places and times wildly divergent (although there may be other "twins" we don't know about). But that's just the kind of coincidence the Mechanism finds. This is an "in-universe" explanation that explains everything, but requires no explanation *within either of the two universes.*

(*) Don't ask me to explain how the uniforms can be so different, that just makes no sense at all.

Comment: I'll have to re-read your answer when I'm more alert. I'd like to ask you to watch the DS9 episode & see if you think your answer still fits. I watched DS9 for the 1st few seasons when it came out in the 90's & didn't like it very much so I didn't watch the last couple of seasons. I didn't really like Sisko. For me Kirk, Picard, & Janeway were amazing. Sisko was difficult for me to sit through. I'm rewatching them though & deciding to give it another chance. I'm finding I still feel in many ways the same as I did the first time. However this episode is a real gem & I encourage you to watch it.

Comment: @JMFB: Sisko is difficult to watch because Avery Brooks is an amazingly bad actor; deep velvety voice, handsome face, three facial expressions and basically nothing else. I don't know whether that, the writing, or the fact that I didn't see the entire series, is the reason I can't recall him ever delivering a really good line.

Comment: I agree completely. He's a horrible actor, at least that's what I attribute it to. He's very mechanical almost like a robot reading lines. There were a few good lines but they're so few that I can't remember one now, which is telling.

Comment: If you add a concept of Universes constantly splitting this works really well. Initial accident creates a strong link between Universe A and Universe B, universes continue to split. Universe A-1678 experiences a new connection, finds similar universe in universe group B (due to previous link); finds B-4568. A-1678 and B-4568 now even more strongly linked

Comment: I feel a **short summary** of this excellent answer is in order.  Beta is just saying: "when you jump to a 'mirror universe', it's a "nearby" one - a very reasonable concept. But note that it is a nearby one ***AT THAT TIME***. (In your universe.) that perfectly explains how the "nearby" universe was indeed "pretty similar' AT THAT TIME, IN EACH CASE."  Quite right.

Comment: In the case of the DS9 episode, contact was initiated from the "other" universe. If you take the Many Worlds interpretation of the multiverse, an easy explanation is that the universe that mirror-O'Brien came from is one that spawned from the one Kirk and Co visited in "Mirror, Mirror". In some variations, Spock's reforms worked. In others, he was crushed before he got the chance, and so on and so forth. Others never had an O'Brien. In all those cases, there was no contact back with the "main" universe because there was no reason or opportunity to do so, so we never heard about them.

Answer (score 4):

This is more into the philosophy behind it than anything direct from canon - but if you think about it, it was quite remarkable in the first recorded instance of a crossover resulting in our Kirk replacing a mirror-Kirk on a mirror-Enterprise crewed with mirror-crew belonging to a mirror-Federation.

He could have just as easily crossed over into a universe where the Shelliac were the dominant Alpha Quadrant race, or one where humans never evolved beyond proto-humans, or...

Or could he?

As you note - there are remarkable similarities in all instances of crossovers. We see Emperor Worf, but we don't really see what else was different about his life history - was mirror-Worf at mirror-Khitimer? Was he adopted by Terrans (probably not given the history of the mirror-Universe)? As for the Cardassians - mirror-Garak is the highest ranked member of his race - no indication of a Dukat or Dumar, or any number of Legats we see in our universe.

So - why is the mirror universe so closely parallel while still deviated?

Well, one thing to note - this is a parallel universe and not a divergent timeline (we are told that these are quite different at a few points in the series).

My guess would be, in-universe, there is something to do with relative subspace energy levels making crossover easier between these two universes as opposed to the multitude of other ones out there.

Out of universe - of course, they want to use the same actors and kind of play "what if" scenarios.

Comment: I like this answer & the one above, but neither addresses one of my primary concerns. I know I'm being specific, but what about offspring? One couple in 5 generations can spawn over 100 people, so killing Quark for example could eliminate 100 people 100 years later in the other universe. So from Kirks time till DS9 even if just a small percentage of people were killed in one universe & not the other, & a small percentage remained alive in one universe and not the other, the makeup of the people and where they're located would be radically different. How do you reconcile that? @Beta & HorusKol

Comment: I think a possible solution is given in Betas answer. "The Universe" chooses a parallel partner, where at all crossover locations and at all crossover times over the whole timeline of both universes (!) there are coincidentaly the same persons. If there are infinite other universes where all exist what is possible, it would finde one. Your problem is solved with having the (apparently) "same" person having different parents or ancestors in both  universes. The only question is why the Universe tries to find a partner where the people look like, but everything else doesn't matter.

Comment: @JMFB: if you like I'll edit my answer to address offspring specifically.

Comment: Another thought - what if each crossover is actually with similar but distinct universes? Each one is different to the last instance?

Comment: @HorusKol hmm... Spock said there are infinite universes, right? I'll have to ponder that for awhile.

Comment: @Beta please do.

Comment: the "Beta theory" explains this perfectly.  Most "multi-universe" ideas today (very much *David Deutsch* line of thinking here) ... feature "just ridiculously many" universes: they **constantly branch in every possible way ... always**.   In that general context, it's extremely reasonable to say that, when you look at one nearby, "it is nearby [similar]".  When you look at one ***at any given time***, it is nearby [similar]. If I look at one now, it's nearby.  If I look at one in 10 years, that one is nearby at that time.

Comment: I feel it's also perfectly reasonable that if I (this year) look at one that us nearby - that's now part of my experiences -  and then, in ten years, look at one that is nearby, then: indeed, those two would be sort of "nearby".  (After all, me looking at the nearby universe is *part of this universe" (!!!).)  I think it would be perfectly acceptable and "how it should be" for anyone into the David Deutsch -type of manymanymanymanymany universes line of thinking. It seems perfectly correct in the current hand-wavey context of "the multiverse"

Answer (score 0):

The exchange in "Mirror, Mirror" could only occur *because* the two universes were so similar.  I've often wondered if the later MU episodes actually did occur in the same universe or merely one that had also been visited by a Jim Kirk from.......somewhere.  I've also heard, but can offer no proof, that they had originally intended to imply that Kirk and company might not have returned to their original universe, but to one that was identical for all intents and purposes but that was abandoned to allow for the Marlena-Prime introduction.