# How can Sisko exist in the Mirror Universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Benjamin Sisko's mother was possessed to ensure he would be born and become the emissary but in the Mirror Universe the wormhole had not been discovered, the prophets had not been met and Sisko was not the emissary.  How could there be a mirror Sisko given these facts?

Comment: You might as well ask [(and people have)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/90455) how *any* of the familiar characters could exist, given the radical differences in the two universes. The answer is: because they already cast the actors. From an in-universe(s) perspective, I don't believe there's even been a canonical answer.

Comment: @Cadence "because they already cast the actors"... I don't _disagree_  .  But I'm left thinking, would I have enjoyed an episode in the mirror universe where Terak Nor existed, and, nobody I recognised appeared?  And my conclusion is, if it was a really good story, yes, that would have been fun and interesting.  But it;'d have to have been very good.  Otherwise I'd have been left with "what was the point of that?" feelings. - of course you're quite right from in universe perspective.  We just get to see (selected by writers!) one of the universes - an interesting one!

Answer (score 9):

Trying to address this from an in-universe perspective, you are missing 1 crucial fact - when Sarah Sisko was possessed by the "prophets," the wormhole had yet to be discovered in the main universe.  The prophet that possessed her left the wormhole to ensure Benjamin Sisko would be born so he could eventually become the emissary (and one of the actions of the emissary was to discover the wormhole).

So there is absolutely no reason to believe that the same thing didn't happen in the mirror universe.  The only difference is the mirror universe Ben Sisko never fulfilled his destiny and discovered the wormhole.

Comment: *"So there is absolutely no reason to believe that the same thing didn't happen in the mirror universe. The only difference is the mirror universe Ben Sisko never fulfilled his destiny and discovered the wormhole."*    --- Well there is a reason right there.   If the reason the prophets did it is because they transcend time and they are aware of what will happen in the future, then they wouldn't possess Sarah Sisko to ensure Benjamin's birth because the emissary would never fulfil the destiny anyhow...

Comment: ... This means you're claiming that A should still happen even though B doesn't happened even though A only happened because B does (through the actions and foreknowledge that B would occur).   Your reasoning makes no sense.

Comment: @ThePopMachine That is assuming the mirror Prophets have the same agenda as the prime ones do, which is unlikely given the general nature of the mirror universe. They might have caused mirror Sisko to be conceived for completely alien and unknowable reasons.

Comment: @ThePopMachine in some ways the mirror universe stories make no sense, I was just trying to come up with an explanation.  The lack of a mirror Jake Sisko calls into question why everyone else exists as he seems to be the only main character in any of the mirror universe stories that doesn't exist in both even when his parents were married in both.  But the hole in my theory you identified is a valid one.

Comment: @Xantec Mirror Prophets? Is that a thing? Or is there only one set of Prophets?

Comment: @StephenCollings We only know that they exist outside of time. Could they exist outside of the universe too? It's possible, but probably impossible to say within canon.

Comment: the whole concept of the mirror universe is illogical when you really think about it.

Comment: @StephenCollings - a mirror prophet is of course a loss.

Comment: In the mirror universe the Pah Wraiths are the prophets.